# What jQuery plugin is used by each Primefaces tag?

Tags: jquery, primefaces

How can I find out what jQuery-UI plugin is used "under the hood" by a given Primefaces component?

I am learning Primefaces. It seems that each Primefaces component packages some or other jQuery plugin to do the user interface work. It is often helpful to see the jQuery API documentation for this component as the Primefaces user guide is not always very detailed.

Comment: It is open source, so you could just browse the source I guess? For example, [this component](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/resources-maven-jsf/ui/accordionPanel.xml).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I find out what jQuery-UI plugin is used "under the hood" by a given Primefaces component?

@Vasan is right in his comment. It is a rather easy point to start.

> I am learning Primefaces.

Great

> It seems that each Primefaces component packages some or other jQuery plugin to do the user interface work.

This to a large extend is wrong. If you mean 'external to PrimeFaces' than this is only partially true. More components use PrimeFaces native code (yes, jquery-ui based) than external ones.

All javascript source is [here](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/tree/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces). And in it you'll see a [jquery folder](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/tree/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/jquery) that shows all plugins that come from jquery itself

Some components use external (not from PrimeFaces or from jquery-ui) client side components. The [fileUpload](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/tree/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/fileupload) does. In this folder you'll see [the source of the external component](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/fileupload/1-jquery.fileupload.js) with in the source references to which component it is.

> ```
> /*
>  * jQuery File Upload Plugin
>  * https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload
>  *
>  * Copyright 2010, Sebastian Tschan
>  * https://blueimp.net
>  *
>  * Licensed under the MIT license:
>  * https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT
>  */
> ```

In the same folder you'll also see [the PrimeFaces 'wrapper'](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/fileupload/2-fileupload.js)

> It is often helpful to see the jQuery API documentation for this component as the Primefaces user guide is not always very detailed.

This has proven to be not true too in my almost 10 years experience working with PrimeFaces. First of all for most functionality there is not a real need for the low level internal workings. And the 'api' in the form of javascript functions is documented in the... well... documentation. But in the occasion you really need the low level details (rarely needed) or want to extend (sometimes needed), the source for me is part of the documentation. The PrimeFaces source is very cleanly written and will help a lot.

So my advice would be to just start using it, remember client-side all is just html, css, javascript and jquery(ui). And also remember the source is open and when you need the details, use the source. Don't start learning PrimeFaces by investigating these details.

Comment: Thanks. You may not appreciate stupid questions from newbies, but the pointers you provide (plus insights other than what was asked) do go a long way to flatten the learning curve. Always appreciated when under time pressure.